# Entity Framework boolean Concurrency Token unexpected behaviour

Tags: c#, concurrency, transactions, entity-framework-core, .net-5

I'm trying to implement an EF transaction which inside has to manage an entity's `ConcurrencyToken` that is a `bool` property.

The idea is that each `IdChain` associated to a `Registry` entity, **can be used only once**. So the `InUse` `bool` property of `MovementsChain` entity has to be set to `true` only from the first concurrent call that comes. All the others, should fail when trying to set the `InUse` property to `true` and then call `Context.SaveChangesAsync()`, so I expect a `DbUpdateConcurrencyException` to be thrown.

##### Entity and its configuration

```
public partial class MovementsChain
{
    public Guid IdChain { get; set; }
    public int IdRegistry { get; set; }
    public DateTime Creation { get; set; }
    public bool InUse { get; set; }
}

public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<MovementsChain> entity)
{
    entity.HasKey(e => e.IdChain);
    
    entity.Property(e => e.IdChain).HasDefaultValueSql("(newid())");

    entity.Property(e => e.Creation).HasDefaultValueSql("(getutcdate())");
    
    entity.Property(e => e.InUse)
        .IsConcurrencyToken();
}
```

##### Transaction

```
// I tried to set different isolation levels for the transaction, like: ReadCommitted and ReadUncommitted, but with no changes in the final behaviour
using (var transaction = await Context.Database.BeginTransactionAsync())
{
    try
    {    
        // Get and lock the IdChain
        var register = await Context.Registers.FirstOrDefaultAsync(/* Predicate... */);

        if (register == null)
            return new TransactionResult(Error.InvalidRegisterIdentifier);

        var movementChain = await Context.MovementsChain
            .OrderByDescending(e => e.Creation)
            .FirstOrDefaultAsync(e => e.IdRegister == register.IdRegister);

        if (movementChain == null)
            return new TransactionResult(Error.IdChainNotFound);

        if (movementChain.InUse)
            return new TransactionResult(Error.IdChainAlreadyInUse);

        // The "core" part of the transaction where the concurrency is managed...
        try
        {
            movementChain.InUse = true;
            await Context.SaveChangesAsync();
        }
        catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException ex)
        {
            // During the tests I never get there...
            return new TransactionResult(Error.IdChainAlreadyInUse); // The specified IdChain is being used by another operation. Cannot proceed.
        }

        // Validation for the client given Guid
        if (request.IdChain == Guid.Empty)
            return new TransactionResult(Error.IdChainNotSpecified);

        if (movementChain.IdChain != request.IdChain)
            return new TransactionResult(Error.InvalidIdChain); // The specified IdChain is not the last one generated by the system. Cannot proceed.
            
        /* The transaction proceeds doing some other stuff...
         * ...
         */
                
        /* Now that the transaction is almost completed and everything has gone well so far,
         * I generate the new Idchain, valid for the next operation
         * and set the current IdChain back to InUse = false.
         */
        
        // Create the new IdChain
        EntityFramework.Models.MovementsChain newMovementChain = new EntityFramework.Models.MovementsChain
        {
            IdRegister = register.IdRegister,
        };

        await Context.MovementsChain.AddAsync(newMovementChain);
                    
        // Unlock the current used IdChain
        movementChain.InUse = false;

        // Save and commit
        await Context.SaveChangesAsync();
        await transaction.CommitAsync();

        return new TransactionResult(Ok);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        await transaction.RollbackAsync();
        throw;
    }
}
```

##### Unit testing

```
[TestMethod]
public async Task CreateMovements_WithSameIdChainInParallel_ReturnsOkJustOne()
{
    int maxConcurrentRequests = 20;
    string idChain = GetLastIdChain(50).ToString();
    int counterStart = 343;
    string payload = @"[
        {{
            ""counter"": {0},
            ""somOtherData"": ""data""
        }}
    ]";

    var contents = new List<StringContent>();

    for (int i = 0; i < maxConcurrentRequests; i++)
    {
        var content = new StringContent(string.Format(payload, counterStart), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
        content.Headers.Add("X-MyApp-IdChain", idChain);
        contents.Add(content);
        counterStart++;
    }

    var responses = new ConcurrentBag<HttpResponseMessage>();
    
    // Multiple Clients using Tasks
    var tasks = contents.Select(async content =>
    {
        using (var client = await CreateClientAsync(content))
        {
            var response = await client.PostAsync(api, content);
            responses.Add(response);
            string responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        }
    }).ToList();
    await Task.WhenAll(tasks);

    Assert.IsTrue(responses.Count(r => r.IsSuccessStatusCode) == 1);
}
```

This test always fails because I usually get 6-7 requests out of the 20, that "correctly" complete with HTTP 200 OK status code. So the same IdChain is used multiple times.

Instead, the correct behaviour should be that **just ONE (the first that is able to lock the IdChain) completes with 200 OK and all the others must fail**.

Comment: You should add a predicate to get `Context.MovementsChain` where not in use. If you fetch one that already has `InUse == true`, `SaveChangesAsync` will do nothing and thus succeed.

Comment: @GertArnold I tried, but I have no changes in the behaviour. I also tried to add a check `if (movimentoChain.InUso) return new TransactionResult(Error.IdChainAlreadyInUse);`, right after the `Context.MovementsChain` query. I also tried each time with different `IsolationLevel`, but nothing... Multiple requests can still use the same `IdChain`.

Comment: OK, but you do need that check. For the rest it's a bit problematic that we don't know your test environment. I assume `client.PostAsync` executes the "Transaction" code, but have things been mocked or is it a full-stack integration test?

Comment: @GertArnold Yes, you're right! In my previous comment I was speaking about the real code, where the check you mentioned was already in place. It was my mistake not to include it in the question code sample. Now I've also updated the code accordingly. Thanks!

Comment: @GertArnold Oh! And yes, the test is done without mocking. The HTTP Client really calls the API endpoint and pass in real data that are written on the real database.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, the problem was that the code responsible to manage the `ConcurrencyToken` was inside the `Transaction` `using` block.
Moving that portion of code outside of the `Transaction`, leads to the correct (and expected) behaviour.

Basically it seems that the `DbUpdateConcurrencyException` is not triggered when the `try/catch` block is inside the `Transaction` block.

The Unit testing method now succeed with 20, 50 and even 100 parallel calls.

This is the updated code of the `Transaction`.

```
// Get and lock the IdChain
var register = await Context.Registers.FirstOrDefaultAsync(/* Predicate... */);

if (register == null)
    return new TransactionResult(Error.InvalidRegisterIdentifier);

var movementChain = await Context.MovementsChain
    .OrderByDescending(e => e.Creation)
    .FirstOrDefaultAsync(e => e.IdRegister == register.IdRegister);

if (movementChain == null)
    return new TransactionResult(Error.IdChainNotFound);

if (movementChain.InUse)
    return new TransactionResult(Error.IdChainAlreadyInUse);

// Validation for the client given Guid
if (request.IdChain == Guid.Empty)
    return new TransactionResult(Error.IdChainNotSpecified);

if (movementChain.IdChain != request.IdChain)
    return new TransactionResult(Error.InvalidIdChain); // The specified IdChain is not the last one generated by the system. Cannot proceed.
    
// The "core" part of the transaction where the concurrency is managed...
try
{
    movementChain.InUse = true;
    await Context.SaveChangesAsync();
}
catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException ex)
{
    // During the tests I never get there...
    return new TransactionResult(Error.IdChainAlreadyInUse); // The specified IdChain is being used by another operation. Cannot proceed.
}

using (var transaction = await Context.Database.BeginTransactionAsync())
{
    try
    {    
        // The transaction starts here, doing its stuff...
                
        /* Now that the transaction is almost completed and everything has gone well so far,
         * I generate the new Idchain, valid for the next operation
         * and set the current IdChain back to InUse = false.
         */
        
        // Create the new IdChain
        EntityFramework.Models.MovementsChain newMovementChain = new EntityFramework.Models.MovementsChain
        {
            IdRegister = register.IdRegister,
        };

        await Context.MovementsChain.AddAsync(newMovementChain);
                    
        // Unlock the current used IdChain
        movementChain.InUse = false;

        // Save and commit
        await Context.SaveChangesAsync();
        await transaction.CommitAsync();

        return new TransactionResult(Ok);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        await transaction.RollbackAsync();
        throw;
    }
}
```

##### Further considerations

In this particular case, there's no issues and/or consequences in moving that part of code outside of the `Transaction` and everything is guaranteed to be robust.

Anyway, to me, there's some things which would require further investigation:

- Is it really this Microsoft's (.NET Team) expected behaviour when `Transaction` and `ConcurrencyToken` objects interact with each other?
- If the answer of the above question is 'Yes', I think that the argument really needs in-depth documentation explaining these modes.
- If the answer instead is 'No'/'Not sure', we may be dealing with strange/unexpected behavior that is worth investigating. So I'm thinking about opening an issue on the .NET 5 GitHub page.